# Implicit Class inheritance in python

Tags: java, python

Is there a way to import classes by importing a class like in Java's `extend`?

```
import sha1sum

class HashFiles():
    def __init__(self):
        a = sha1sum.Sha1SumClass()
        for path in glob.glob('./*'):
            print(a.sha1sum(path))
```

As in this example the only import is a custom class defined in the `__init__.py` and, as in this example, I would like to inherit all imported classes (i.e. `glob`) without explicitly importing in the current class. Obviously as it stands this will fail because I didn't import `glob` explicitly. Is there a way in python to do this?

Comment: No. Python sticks to *Explicit is better than implicit* here; it will not implicitly import global names that are not defined.

Comment: Is it possible to do relative path importing in python? I've tried to do that as well, in failure.

Comment: Yes it is possible with command : import.
It is simillar with JAVA, you choose your module in packages. Packages are folder with an __init__.py file.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. Python imports can be made relative to the current package, if that is what you mean; within package `foo` any module can import from other modules within that package with `import foo.name` or `import .name`.

Comment: I mean `from . import *`, or something similar, without explicitly naming each package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you can do `__all__ = ['*']` in `__init__.py`.
Not certain that's how I want to define everything, 
but I suppose it works for now. 
I'm thinking that keeping that in code would be a terribly bad standard.